# Show UTF-8 characters in console

Tags: c#

How can I print UTF8 characters in the console?

With `Console.Writeline("îăşâţ")` I see `îasât` in console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some hacks you can find that demonstrate how to write multibyte character sets to the Console, but they are unreliable.  They require your console font to be one that supports it, and in general, are something I would avoid.  (All of these techniques break if your user doesn't do extra work on their part... so they are not reliable.)

If you need to write Unicode output, I highly recommend making a GUI application to handle this, instead of using the Console.  It's fairly easy to make a simple GUI to just write your output to a control which supports Unicode.

Comment: I'm going to assume `Console.OutputEncoding` did not exist in early 2010, but it would be nice to mention in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 98):

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: if your font broken, also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console#5750227

Comment: For Windows 10, and getting required fonts check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54327996/378783

Comment: Why we might get `System.IO.IOException: 'The handle is invalid.` for that command?

Comment: Maybe unpack what UTF8 is in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Try this :

```
using System.Diagnostics
...
Debug.WriteLine(..);// will output utf-8 charset
```

Comment: Writes it to where, exactly?  Not my console.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline

Comment: @MaximPaperno It writes to the Visual Studio Debugger console. Which is fortunate, because the top-rated answer does not work in that context _(it throws the "handle is invalid" error mentioned in the comments)_

Answer (score 5):

Using Console.OutputEncoding will be sufficient for this. All string objects in .NET are by default unicode so changing output encoding for console to UTF-8 will work as you want in modern Windows installations.

Default encoding in console depends on configuration but it will be most likely IBM437 for US language or some local codepage.

Comment: I tried setting the `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode` but now non western characters are displayed as little rectangles. Interestingly, if I mark the text in the console and paste it here I get the original unicode (e.g. `汤姆·福特`).
PS: I'm using Windows Server 2016 my region is set to United Kingdom.

Answer (score 3):

You can't print Unicode characters in the console, it only supports the characters that are available in the current code page. Characters that are not available are converted to the closest equivalent, or a question mark.

Comment: Consider UTF8 has a codepage (65001), this suggests you only need to switch code pages?

Comment: @MSalters: The console can normally only use 8 bit codepages.

Comment: Not true. You can just set "chcp 65001". I use ConEmu along with this setting to display Unicode fonts without any issues.

Comment: @jhclark: Yes, that's not a regular console window.

Answer (score 0):

Window form does not support console output encoding.
You need to install locale language to support command display language encoding

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).