# How to write Unicode characters to the console?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, console-application

I was wondering if it was possible, in a console application, to write characters like `℃` using .NET. When I try to write this character, the console outputs a question mark.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

It's likely that your output encoding is set to ASCII. Try using this before sending output:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

(MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) to supporting documentation.)

And here's a little console test app you may find handy:

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public static class ConsoleOutputTest {
    public static void Main() {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            Console.Write(Strings.ChrW(i));
            if (i % 50 == 0) { // break every 50 chars
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
imports System

public module ConsoleOutputTest 
    Sub Main()
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        dim i as integer
        for i = 0 to 1000
            Console.Write(ChrW(i))
            if i mod 50 = 0 'break every 50 chars 
                Console.WriteLine()
            end if
        next
    Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
end module
```

It's also possible that your choice of Console font does not support that particular character. Click on the Windows Tool-bar Menu (icon like C:.) and select Properties -> Font. Try some other fonts to see if they display your character properly:

[image: picture of console font edit]

Comment: thanks, the "console.outputEncoding" was what i was looking for, but unfortunately i dont think the character was supported by my font. can you expand on the windows toolbar menu thing? thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Yes, it's the little icon in the upper, left-hand corner of your console window that looks like a tiny version of a console. Every Windows window (that has a title and border) has this. Just click on it to see a menu, one of the options will be Properties. Click on that and find the Font tab to tweak your fonts.

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding` cannot be set to `Encoding.Unicode`(UTF-16). `Encoding.UTF8`, however, is possible.

Comment: In .NET 4.5 and later also UTF-16 is supported

Comment: hm, this doesn't work for me.  I'm trying to print out hindi or korean and no luck

Comment: You may need for restart the app to see effect after switching between fonts.

Comment: Looks like setting the encoding and using Consolas works for Russian letters (after restart of the console app; with .NET 4.5.1), but not for Korean nor for Chinese.. And cannot seem to choose any fonts that work for these..

Comment: Be aware even after you set Encoding and choose fonts (not many to choose from), there are still characters that cannot be displayed. I actually had to change to GUI to finally solve the issue.

Comment: @Gildor: you are right, but you might be able to find a monospaced font that does support your character set. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30040/Font-Survey-42-of-the-Best-Monospaced-Programming)

Comment: The C# example will not work unless you add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and add a using for `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.

Comment: @Cel: I've found that NSimSun works for Chinese and Japanese (as well as English).

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8` and the `SimHei` font made it possible to display chinese characters for me. 谢谢!

Comment: char.ConvertFromUtf32() instead of Strings.ChrW() for C#..   Strings.ChrW() is a VB Call.

Answer (score 14):

I found some elegant solution on MSDN

```
System.Console.Write('\uXXXX') //XXXX is hex Unicode for character
```

This simple program writes ℃ right on the screen.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write('\u2103'); //℃ character code
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really neat! However I think the accepted answer still applies - if the font that the console is using does not support unicode characters, I believe this example will not work. I can't check that, however, as I don't have access to a Windows computer at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I believe Sam is correct. I for instance was stuck in the fact that the command prompt fonts did not support my character set.

Comment: This answer works best for most things I do -- I let the console default to its font, and I use the trick of setting the output type to UTF8 (shown in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 13):

**Console.OutputEncoding Property**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding

> Note that successfully displaying Unicode characters to the console requires the following:
>
> - The console must use a TrueType font, such as Lucida Console or Consolas, to display characters.

Answer (score 13):

Besides `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`

for some characters you need to install extra fonts (ie. Chinese).

In ***Windows 10*** first go to ***Region & language settings*** and install support for required language:
[image]

After that you can go to ***Command Prompt Proporties (or Defaults if you like)*** and choose some font that supports your language (like ***KaiTi*** in Chinese case):
[image]

Now you are set to go:
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. Change the Console Font is the fix for me :) (Also set console out put to use UTF-8)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

`Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;`

To display some of the symbols, it's required to set Command Prompt's font to Lucida Console:

1. Open Command Prompt;
2. Right click on the top bar of the Command Prompt;
3. Click Properties;
4. If the font is set to Raster Fonts, change it to Lucida Console.