# How are latin based characters seen?

Tags: c#, unicode, latin

I am going to write a simple console app in C# that replaces all Latin based characters with their respectively defined replacedment (like Å (ALT+143) becomes AA).

I was wondering how it is viewed in C#. Would it be seen as the string "\uC5" or "\u00C5" or "Å" or something else?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In the meantime you can provide us with some code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Explain what you mean with _"how it is viewed in C#"_.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write unicode chars to console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-chars-to-console)

Comment: You need to be more explicit. C# is not a text visualisation system, it's a programming language.

Comment: @CodeCaster It is not the same as the question asked in the linked you shared. I was just trying to understand how C# reads/understands/views latin based characters. As humans, we see it as a series of characters, what does the compiler see it as, which I have now found the answer to.

Comment: That is why I asked for clarification on what you mean by _"How it is viewed"_. Now you name "compiler" for the first time, which renders the accepted answer incorrect. The compiler sees characters in .cs files _as they are in the file_. If you type `"\uNNNN"`, the compiler reads a string of six characters: `\uNNNN`, and will parse that into an Unciode character. If you _type_ a  character like `☺` (\u263A) and save the file in an Unicode encoding like UTF-8, the compiler sees one character: the one you typed. The compiler operates on text files, so what you see in there is what you get.

Comment: So, I don't know what you can do with the currently given answers. It could really prove helpful if you could explain your actual problem, like _"How do I compare Unicode characters?"_ or whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @CodeCaster I was trying to replace Latin based characters with their respectively defined replacement. So if there is Å and I say I want to replaced all Å with AA, then I search through the string for Å and replace it with AA. Ex. ÅBBÅBBB becomes AABBAABBB. Before I could do that, I had to first understand how Å was represented.

Comment: _"Before I could do that, I had to first understand how Å was represented."_ - From your description and comments it still isn't clear what you mean, nor does it seem relevant to the compiler. I guess all you wanted to know is the [`char` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx). Anyway good for you you got this sorted out.

Comment: @CodeCaster May I ask why you sound as if you are mad? I mean if you aren't here to help people, why post? I understand that I wasn't as clear as you wanted me to be, but you have to realize that I don't understand the material as well as you do.

Comment: I'm absolutely not mad, I just tried to understand your problem so it can be worded in a way that is useful for other readers. :) I mean - if you could perhaps have shown a bit of code and explain what that code is supposed to do, it would be a _lot_ more clear than _"How does C# view Unicode"_. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is (almost!) always viewed as a character literal in format "\u00C5".

See [this article on Char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay(v=vs.110).aspx).

and [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx) specifically on character literals which, while outdated, still applies in the latest version of .NET.

Answer (score 1):

C# strings are Unicode, so it will be shown as is