# how to get html content charset in c#?

Tags: c#, html, httpclient

i am using

```
HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url)
```

to get the content of a webpage, and then get a certain tag's innerText. by default, the response is okay, but when the target webpage has the following metadata, it will cause messy code

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
```

so how can i know its charset and use it like this?

```
var byteData = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
var Encoding.GetEncoding("name").GetString(byteData)
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11018883/492258) may be answer to your question

Comment: or this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829440/how-to-get-the-html-encoding-right-in-c

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak i have seen it before, but seems not relevant to me. if the target web page without <meta charset="utf-8"> defined(actually i use this in a web crawler application) the HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url) also cause messy code.