# Failed to print char in console

Tags: c#, .net, console, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to print a char in console but when I do it, the console print other char.
The char in question is ³ and I use:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToChar(0xb3));
```

When I use the last code the console print "3".

If I try print the char 0xb2 it works.

Comment: What are you trying to do, what is happening now, and what do you want the output to be?

Comment: I want the output "³" (char 179) but when I try print Convert.ToChar(179) it print "3".

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
Console.WriteLine("\u00b3");
```

Answer (score 0):

See

- [Console.OutputEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Unicode Support For Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx#Unicode)
- [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-chars-to-console)

You'll also need to make sure that your console is configured to use a TrueType font that supports Unicode (or at least, that subset of Unicode in which you're interested).

Comment: I test change the font but it dont work, the console can't print "³" I dont know why.