# Output sad smiley in c# console program

Tags: c#, console

I searched through the net but didn't found a solution for printing a sad smiley in a c# console Program.

I can print a happy smiley using:

```
    Console.Write((char)1);
```

I also tried:

```
    Console.Write('\u2639'.ToString());
```

But it only appears a '?' on the console.

Could someone please help me?

Thx (:

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5750203/656243

Comment: As well as requiring a font that contains that glyph