# EGP currency in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

How to make an `int` variable show as currency in console app. Begin with EGP. I tried the following code, but it only shows the Arabic as "ج.م", not EGP.

```
 double x = 12.5;
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("C",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-EG")));
```

But the result is: `?.?.? 12.5` instead of "EGP" because it is in Arabic language. What I need is to make it EGP 12.5 not "ج.م"

[image]

Comment: Take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-chars-to-console It's about displaying unicode characters in the console.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ but he doesn't *want* to display unicode characters in the console: 'What I need is to make it EGP 12.5 not "ج.م"'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EGP is the [ISOCurrencySymbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.isocurrencysymbol(v=vs.110).aspx) for Egyptian Pound.

This should work for you.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
public class PrintCurrencyValue  {
   public static void Main()  {
      double x = 12.5;
      RegionInfo myRI1 = new RegionInfo( "ar-EG" );
      Console.WriteLine( "CurrencySymbol:    {0} {1:N}", myRI1.CurrencySymbol, x);
      Console.WriteLine( "ISOCurrencySymbol: {0} {1:N}", myRI1.ISOCurrencySymbol, x);
   }
}
```