# console.writeline cannot display Chinese characters

Tags: c#

Background:

1. I have a table in SQL database, two of the columns are English names and Simplified Chinese names.
2. With C#, I had records of this table displayed as buttons with both names, such as: Car车. This is how I did it:
   `button.Text = x.EnglishName + x.ChineseName;` The buttons displays correctly.

3.I would like to compare button.Text to other strings, like so:

```
for (int K = 0; K < alist.Count; K++)
{
 string alpha = alist.[K];
 if (alpha == button.Text)
 //blahblahblah
}
```

Problem:

There is always an error.
And I found out why: when I use `Console.Writeline(button.Text)`, the output is Car?.
Each Chinese character is turned into a "?"

So, apparently, writing Chinese characters onto the face of a button is fine. But when reading Chinese characters off the face of a button does not work.

How do I correct this?

Comment: What character code encoding do you have console set to by default? Character encoding can also be limited by the default console font

Comment: Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Comment: _There is always an error._ What is the error?

Comment: Console.outputencoding = encoding.XXX does not work, I have tried UTF8,7,32,UNICODE all those available...

Comment: see this link, setting this way also works on CMD. 

if your cmd can show chinese, your console can show chinese.  

https://www.walkernews.net/2013/05/19/how-to-get-windows-command-prompt-displays-chinese-characters/

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate of linked question as it requires some extra actions! But I have created extra answer in linked question with Chinese specific actions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54327996/378783

Answer (score 1):

You might need to change the Encoding type -

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode  // For UTF-16
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) for other encoding types available.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work, still jibberish...

Comment: This may not be enough for Chinese, check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54327996/378783