# How to print a chess piece(unicode) in c#?

Tags: chess

i saw a question about this subject before i posted it and i tried everthing they suggested, didn't work.([How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console))
this is the code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.WriteLine("\u2654");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

and that's what i get in the console:
https://gyazo.com/682aa298f5d55d1a037bf1d12ef910b1 .
i expected a king symbol at the console.
anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your choice of Console font does not support that particular character. Click on the Windows Toolbar Menu and select Properties -> Font. Try some other fonts to see if they display your character properly. With MS Gothic

[image: MS Gothic]