# c# special characters compare strings

Tags: c#, special-characters

I have a problem with these two special characters from romanian language: `ț` and `ș`.

**Example:** 
`String s = "ștrumf";`

The result is `?trumf` when I write the string to console.
Does anyone know what  may be the reason?

Comment: Console font may be missing accented characters. Try choosing a different font in the console's settings dialog.

Comment: Does changing that to `string s = @"ștrumf";` make any difference?

Comment: Is your only problem how it looks on the console? Then modify the title. Otherwise it's not helpful for future readers.

Comment: I suppose you are using Visual Studio, what happen if you inspect the value of s variable breakpointing just on the next line?
Do you see the string correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Note that you need `using System.Text;`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this before sending output:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Checkout this [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5750227/6205166)

Answer (score 1):

You, should set Console.OutputEncoding as UTF8

> ```
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
>         String s = "ștrumf";
>         Console.WriteLine(s);
>         Console.ReadLine();
>     }
> ```