# Write Hebrew in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to write In Hebrew language with C# visual 2015 .NET Framework 4.5.2

I have tried:

```
        string str = "עברית";

        Encoding hebrewEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");

        byte[] bytes = hebrewEncoding.GetBytes(str);

        string hebrewString = hebrewEncoding.GetString(bytes);

        Console.WriteLine(hebrewString);
```

But the output is: `?????`

Comment: That exact snippet works fine for me.

Comment: Which font do you use? I had similar problem on Windows 10 with Chinese: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54327996/378783