# How to display tamil text "தமிழ்" in c# console window?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, console-application, tamil

As it is shown in below examples, i have tried various techniques to display tamil text by parsing its unicode content to the output window and it doesn't work. Please suggest as where i'm going wrong?

```
private static void PrintInTamil1()
{
    const string str = "தமிழ்"; // this is already a unicode string.

    byte[] stringBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
    char[] stringChars = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(stringBytes);

    foreach (var chr in stringChars)
    {
        // unicode character code
        var unicoded = ((int)chr).ToString();

        // hex character code
        var hexcoded = @"\u" + ((int)chr).ToString("X4").ToLower();

        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        // print to VS output window
        Console.WriteLine(chr + "     " + unicoded + "     " + hexcoded);
    }
}

private static void PrintInTamil2()
{
    byte[] unicodeBytes = new byte[]
    {0x61, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x63, 0x61,
     0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x2F, 0x70, 0x63,
     0x61, 0x70};

    string unicodeString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unicodeBytes);

    Console.WriteLine(unicodeString);
}        

private static void PrintInTamil()
{
    string str = "தமிழ்";
    var myarray2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    string unicodeString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myarray2);
    Console.WriteLine(unicodeString);
}
```

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8\Unicode;` then you will need a font that can display those characters, set the console property page to that font. which i think is going to be the hard part. none of the fonts i had could display those charcters

Comment: Try installing Office 2013 or lower. It comes with Ariel Unicode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console)