# MySql character encoding problem - currency sign (¤)

Tags: c#, mysql, character-encoding, character, console-application

I have an issue displaying the typographic currency sign (¤)  in a console application.
The Console is showing ()(pasted, which does not show up here) - a boxed question mark: [image]
The database character set is utf8 with collation utf8_general_ci.
The table and fields are set to the same.
The connection string has CharSet=utf8;

In Navicat, changing the encoding or collation has no effect on the display - it is always a (¤).
I have been searching the web for a while with no avail, so any help would be much aprreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console)

Comment: Right! -  you saved me heaps of time thanks! Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 did the trick