# Can I use Unicode in a C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, unicode, unicode-escapes

I tried to use this code:

[image: Code]

But I get this all the time:

[image: Output]

Is there a way to "convert" this?

Comment: Change font? Change codepage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console)

Comment: @WaiHaLee not its not my question

Comment: I would argue that it's exactly the same as your question - to the point where it's a duplicate. The solution proposed, that you've said works (and have accepted), is given as an answer on the question I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you need to convert it:
[image: yes you need to convert it:]

you need to make a "\" that will show the program, that you are not just simply type any characters.

you can find the Unicode on many websites [for example here](https://www.quackit.com/character_sets/unicode/versions/unicode_9.0.0/miscellaneous_symbols_unicode_character_codes.cfm)

than you will get your Smiley, this dose not work with every Unicode Character!
[image: Converted Picture]

kindly regards Juan ☺

Comment: thank you for your time, handling my problem, now its working for me