# dotnet core System.Text.Json unescape unicode string

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core, system.text.json

Using `JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj)` will produce an escaped string, but I want the unescaped version. For example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new A{Name = "你好"};
        var s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(a);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

class A {
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

will produce a string `{"Name":"\u4F60\u597D"}` but I want `{"Name":"你好"}`

I created a code snippet at https://dotnetfiddle.net/w73vnO
Please help me.

Comment: Aside from making the data less readable, the default escaping also bloats the size of the json by 40 percent.  And that is a significant change when you are caching or sending large json payloads.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You need to set the JsonSerializer options not to encode those strings.

```
JsonSerializerOptions jso = new JsonSerializerOptions();
jso.Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping;
```

Note that [using `UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping` comes with security risks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/character-encoding#serialize-all-characters) such as XSS attacks.

Then you pass this options when you call your `Serialize` method.

```
var s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(a, jso);
```

Full code:

```
JsonSerializerOptions jso = new JsonSerializerOptions();
jso.Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping;

var a = new A { Name = "你好" };
var s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(a, jso);        
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Result:

[image]

If you need to print the result in the console, you may need to install additional language. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console/54327996#54327996).

Comment: I could not believe my eyes when I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.unsaferelaxedjsonescaping?view=netcore-3.0

This is extremely surprising behavior by the default encoder.

Comment: It's important to understand the potential concerns with using this in your scenario and I would recommend safer alternatives if feasible. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?view=netcore-3.0#serialize-all-characters

Comment: Those docs never mention _why_ they avoid serializing those.  Why was the decision made to encode everything when characters like the double-quote `"` and control chars have specific escape sequences for them?!

Comment: Using an "unsafe" encoding is not the answer, the answer from ahsonkhan is correct

Comment: I had to sign up to stackoverflow to upvote this! I agree that it is not safe but it answers the question.

Comment: @gregsdennis the docs do mention why such a decision was made (choosing safer defaults for security): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-encoding?view=netcore-3.0

Comment: Can't we override the global settings?

Comment: Superb! This helped me a lot with Polish diacretic characters. Thx

Comment: Be careful with this since it can result in XSS attacks! See @ahsonkhan's answer instead!

Answer (score 55):

To change the escaping behavior of the `JsonSerializer` you can pass in a custom `JavascriptEncoder` to the `JsonSerializer` by setting the `Encoder` property on the `JsonSerializerOptions`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.encoder?view=netcore-3.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_Encoder

The default behavior is designed with security in mind and the `JsonSerializer` over-escapes for defense-in-depth.

If all you are looking for is escaping certain "alphanumeric" characters of a specific non-latin language, I would recommend that you instead create a `JavascriptEncoder` using the `Create` factory method rather than using the `UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping` encoder.

```cs
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin, UnicodeRanges.CjkUnifiedIdeographs)
};

var a = new A { Name = "你好" };
var s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(a, options);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Doing so keeps certain safe-guards, for instance, HTML-sensitive characters will continue to be escaped.

**I would caution against using** `System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping` flippantly since it does minimal escaping (which is why it has "unsafe" in the name). If the JSON you are creating is written to a UTF-8 encoded file on disk or if its part of web request which explicitly sets the charset to utf-8 (and is not going to potentially be embedded within an HTML component as is), then it is probably OK to use this.

See the remarks section within the API docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.unsaferelaxedjsonescaping?view=netcore-3.0#remarks

You could also consider specifying `UnicodeRanges.All` if you expect/need all languages to remain un-escaped. This still escapes certain ASCII characters that are prone to security vulnerabilities.

```cs
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All)
};
```

**For more information and code samples, see**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?view=netcore-3.0#customize-character-encoding

[**See the Caution Note**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LyOf.png)

Comment: @joey I know this came later but it should become the accepted answer

Comment: Here's the updated doc page link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-encoding?view=netcore-3.0

Comment: "If the JSON you are creating is written to a UTF-8 encoded file on disk or if its part of web request which explicitly sets the charset to utf-8 (and is not going to potentially be embedded within an HTML component as is), then it is probably OK to use this. [UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping]" to highlight this part

Answer (score 15):

Use:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All)
};
```

Comment: that's the way, thx

Answer (score 11):

You can use: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(string)` to unescape the unicode characters.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape

Updating example from original question:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            var a = new A{Name = "你好"};
            var s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(a);
        
            var unescaped = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(s);

            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine(unescaped);
        }
}

class A {
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Output:

```
{"Name":"\u4F60\u597D"}
{"Name":"你好"}
```

Comment: This works the best for all cases.