# How to custom serialise json with .net core and JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

My implementation returns a string where the json propertyname strings are escaped. This doesn't match the json format and brings up some problems. Is there a way to use the JsonSerializer, or do I have to build the output property for property from hand like suggested in the Microsoft documentation.

So my serialization seems to work, but putting it in a proper json format seems to fail.

```
        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IMyInterface value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case Implementation1 i1:
                    writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(i1, options));
                    return;
                case Implementation2 i2:
                    writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(i2, options));
                    return;
                case Implementation3 i3:
                    writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(i3, options));
                    break;
            }
        }
```

This is part of the result e.g. : `["{\"propertyName\":null,...`

Update:

I updated like suggested the JsonSerializer options so that it doesn't encode like this in my `Startup.cs` in the `ConfigureServices`, which seems to not fix the problem.

```
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts =>
            {
                opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping;
            });
```

Comment: Why are you building escaped JSON?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dotnet core System.Text.Json unescape unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003293/dotnet-core-system-text-json-unescape-unicode-string)

Comment: @mason Thats the question, I don't want to build it escaped, I want it in the propert json format.

Comment: @RoarS.It seems to match, but I doesn't change the output. I will update how I integrated it in my code.

Answer (score 2):

As @GeorgeSquair already explained, `JsonSerializer.Serialize()` converts my object into a json string and passing the value into `writer.WriteStringValue()` will repeat this, resulting in escaping the property names. I checked the parameters of the `JsonSerializer.Serialize()` and found out, that I can pass in the writer as parameter which solves this issue properly.

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IMyInterface value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case Implementation1 i1:
                    JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, i1, options);
                    return;
                case Implementation2 i2:
                    JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, i2, options);
                    return;
                case Implementation3 i3:
                    JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, i3, options);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `JsonSerializer.Serialize()` your object is converted into a string, representing json.

Next passing the result of this call into `writer.WriteStringValue()` will write a string value as json, which in turn will be escaping the characters in the string which you've already serialized into json.

Try using the `JsonSerializerOptions` instead.

`JsonSerializer.Serialize(i1, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true });`

Comment: Makes sense! Your solution brings this result : `["{\r\n  \"propertyName\": null...` which is a change but unfortunately isn't correct either.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should have read the documentation.

[WriteStringValue(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writestringvalue?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonWriter_WriteStringValue_System_String_): Writes a **string text value (as a JSON string)** as an element of a JSON array.

You probably want [WriteString(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writestring?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonWriter_WriteString_System_String_System_String_): Writes a **property name specified as a string and a string text value (as a JSON string)** as part of a name/value pair of a JSON object.

Comment: Well this would lead me to manually iterating my whole object and write the json property for property like I already mentioned in my question... I posted a convenient solution which works.