# c# Save korean string to file, not utf form string

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

There is a class, Data.
Data has a member, "name" which contains Korean string.

I make json string with System.Text.Json

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize<Data>(data, opt);
```

and make json file

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonstring, Encoding.UTF8);
```

part of json is

> "name": "**\uC0BC\uC131\uC804\uAE30**",

but Json string what I want  is

> "name": "**삼성전기**",

I tried

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonstring, Encoding.Unicode)
File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonstring, Encoding.Default)
```

but the contents of the file are in this format \uxxxx.

How can I save  Korean string to file as it is?

(As a reference)
When I try to find solution (for C#) I found out function(json.dumps) in Python
I can get the results what I want by using it

(example)

```
import json
dict = {'555': '123'}
with open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
file.write(json.dumps(dict))
```

Comment: What is the value in `jsonstring` ? If `jsonstring` contains `"name": "\uC0BC\uC131\uC804\uAE30"`, then **that is what the string contains**, and what it will always contain. How you encode that *doesn't matter*; the real question then moves back a step: how to get `JsonSerializer` to not escape those values. Can you show the code that produces `jsonstring`? Note: this *probably* comes down to setting `opt.Encoder = ...` (to something)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [dotnet core System.Text.Json unescape unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58003293/3744182), agree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want here is - *right at the start*:

```cs
opt.Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping;
```

(obviously don't change this constantly - set it once only; if a different usage needs different options: use a different options object)

This leaves the `Name` unescaped, rather than escaping it *in the JSON*. *From there*, you can then encode the `string` any way you like.

You should also note that the name `UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping` suggests that there may be scenarios in which this is undesirable, so: it would be worth trying to [read the documentation on `UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.unsaferelaxedjsonescaping) to understand *when and why this is*.