# JsonNode.Parse wrong UTF8

Tags: c#, json

I have this Json string which I'll need to convert into an JsonNode.

```
{"3":"Maybachstraße 14","4":"45659","5":"Recklinghausen","6":"1","7":""}
```

However, the JSON node always believes that the JSON is this string instead:

```
{"3":"Maybachstra\u00DFe 14","4":"45659","5":"Recklinghausen","6":"1","7":""}
```

[image: Code]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: They're not wrong. As far as JSON is concerned, these two are the same. Why do *you* need to distinguish between them?

Comment: It's just two different ways to display [Unicode](https://unicodemap.org/details/0x00DF/index.html)

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003293/dotnet-core-system-text-json-unescape-unicode-string)

Comment: How do I get the console to output "Maybachstraße 14" then with this JsonNode?

Comment: With your current code: `Console.WriteLine(node.AsObject()["3"].ToString())`. This will cast the node to an object, get the value of key "3" and convert it to a string, which will return "Maybachstraße 14".

Comment: @MarvinKlein it is just the way it is visualized. If you try Console.WriteLine(tmp["3"]) you will see  the way you like it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dotnet core System.Text.Json unescape unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58003293/dotnet-core-system-text-json-unescape-unicode-string)