# How to display a spacial code (e.g., triangular bullet: \u2023) n times with c# Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, unicode, console

How can I display spacial codes in c# `Console.WriteLine()`?

Given:  `symbol = '\u2023';`
The escape sequence `\u2023` should display `‣` on console in c#. So, How can I get output for the symbol as `'‣'` and not `'?'`

What I get is just a wrong symbole `'?'` instead.

[image: Wrong display of triangle bullet character in c# console]

```
public void DisplayPattern (int n, char symbol)
{
    string pattern = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        pattern = new String(symbol, i);                  
        Console.WriteLine(pattern);
    }
}
```

Comment: Console can only show ASCII characters.

Comment: it should be possible by using:         // The encoding: 
        UnicodeEncoding unicode = new UnicodeEncoding(); but I dont know how to develop my function to get the output right!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I used this method but the question marks turned in to squares not triangle!

Comment: @AliSafari change the font. MS Gothic shows the triangle for me.

Comment: Yes, It works. thank you very much, indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the console encoding

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Console.Write('\u2023');
```

now it depends if you use a font that supports that character. `Consolas` doesn't.

Comment: Do you know how can I change my console font?

Comment: @AliSafari right, change the font of your console like Crowcoder mentioned. (right click on console bar, properties, font, Gothic)

Comment: @AliSafari the link to the duplicate question I posted shows you how to change the font

Comment: Sorry @fubo, where I have to do the right click? If you mean on cmd.exe? then I don't see any font tab on this app.

Answer (score 0):

So with help of you guys I write the answer down:
As @fubo said: 
first add:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

then choose an appropriate font like what @Crowcoder said: MS Gothic will turn all the question marks into triangle bullets.

[image: Right display of symbols in c# console]