# Is there a specific way of defining the language for HTML Decode?

Tags: c#, html

Hi guys i have a piece of html encoded text :`&#35831;` -> 请
I tried using the following functions: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode/=WebUtility.HtmlDecode to decode it but it gives me a question mark. However when i try something like an online HTML decoder, I'm able to see the proper chinese character
How can i choose the language for it to be outputted to?

Comment: This is an encoding issue

Comment: @Cid, What do you mean it's an encoding issue? I'm not very familiar with HTML encoding and would appreciate if you could give more details so i could look into it..

Comment: It may be correctly decoded. How are you displaying it ?

Comment: @Cid Ah, right. Then it's probably an encoding/font issue then.

Comment: @Sweeper, Hi actually it already has the ; at the end, i left it out on accident

Comment: @Cid, I am merely capturing it as a string value and Writing to my console output. Could this be the reason why I am just seeing a question mark?

Comment: @TravisTeo try `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` and then, try again displaying in the console

Comment: Could be related [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console)

Comment: @Cid, Thanks for the prompt replies, I've tried UTF8 Encoding but it displays it as a question mark symbol within a box now

Comment: @Cid, you're right, the link you have provided was insightful. Thanks for the help, if you would like i could mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: If this link solved your problem, better to mark this question as duplicate