# How to use MeCab in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a documentation on how to use meCab ?.

I am new in Visual studio and c#. I already have meCab downloaded ( https://github.com/taku910/mecab ).

Best Regards.

Comment: describe what you have done and what exact problem you faced

Comment: Actually, I'm stucked cause I'm not quiet sure what to do next because I thought in visual studio adding a library is just about adding the reference(dll file) but I can't seem to find the dll file in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started from the wrong side: repository you provided is more like model itself rather than "plug and play" dll and the last c# commit was 7 years ago (i.e outdated)

Have a look at this one: https://github.com/kekyo/MeCab.DotNet

its new, has Nuget package (our .NET tool to install things in one click), has  basic example and most likely you can concat author directly on github.

1. You need to create new .NET Core console project
2. Run `Install-Package MeCab.DotNet -Version 0.0.26` in package manager console
3. Copy paste example code from https://github.com/kekyo/MeCab.DotNet
4. Contact author if needed

Comment: uhm. Got it to work thanks :). tho when I return back to my work all the output turns into "?".

Comment: @KevinLaguitan see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console