# Console application prints differently than online compiler

Tags: c#, printing, console, read-eval-print-loop

I am writing a program for connect 4 that works very well.
Only problem is that in visual studio the method

```
    public static void Display(char[,] board)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" " + i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("_");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("|" + board[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine('|');
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("¯");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

prints the last for loop too low. It is inadequate.
It should be like that (works in repl)
[image]

but gets printed like that (in VS) [image]

I tried to use ¯ instead of ‾ but it just printed out question marks ??????????

Comment: Some characters can't be translated in some editors

Comment: Note that that's not in Visual Studio. Visual Studio doesn't actually execute your code. Anyway, 1) ¯ isn't a standard ASCII character, so that's probably why it shows ????. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console). 2) It appears to be a font difference, or since it's HTML, perhaps they are doing something different with the line-by-line vertical alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using the good old [Box Drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) characters?

You will have an output like this:

[image]

```
public static void Display(char[,] board)
{
    Console.Clear();

    Console.Write(" ");
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(" " + i + "  ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.Write("┌");
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("───┬");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("───┐");

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("│" + " " + board[i, j] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("│");

        Console.Write(i < 5 ? "├───┼" : "└───┴");
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(i < 5 ? "───┼" : "───┴");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(i < 5 ? "───┤" : "───┘");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Those are not ASCII characters (which is why the title of the page you linked does not actually contain the word ASCII - unlike your link description)

Comment: Thank you a lot sire. You are a genius. Can I get some insight on how you have found all of these characters? Where do you look them up when in trouble?

Comment: @sepp2k fixed the link description

Comment: @Algo been taught them in college, q basic

Comment: "Where do you look them up when in trouble?" there is [this pdf document](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2500.pdf) in the link which contains the Range: 2500–257F from the unicode standard. And if this answer solved your problem, you can tick the check mark and accept it.