# c# split method doesn't work with cyrillic

Tags: c#, unicode, split

My code is

```
string[] separate = { ",", ", " };
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] values = input.Split(separate, 4, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

It works perfectly fine with numbers and latin letters, but when I use cyrillic it returns an empty string

For Example if I type in "cyrillic, кирилица, 1, 3" it returns

```
cyrillic

1
3
```

Comment: Seems to work fine when I try to reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pLKUBJ Are you sure something else isnt going on?

Comment: Can you show us what is value you entered as an input

Comment: @PrasadTelkikarits in the question already

Comment: In the question, but not in code. OP is either not using the string they think they're using, or the commas are some kind of special Cyrillic comma, not the usual ASCII one.

Comment: Maybe [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5750203/15498) is relevant