# Is it possible to redefine ASCII Characters in C#

Tags: c#, terminal

I've been learning more and more about C# and it's terminal. And I want to change the look of certain ASCII characters. The reason why I want to is because I want to make an ASCII game and I need certain characters to be objects, but there are no characters for what I need. I'm just wondering is it possible to change a character into a completely different character. Like change the character A into a rock for example.

Comment: The answer is yes... to a degree. have a look at changing the font of the console

Comment: You may just need to wait a bit https://emojipedia.org/rock/ may be available at some point... While answer suggested by @Gusman points you to the path to answer *exactly* what question is asking about (you still need custom font but creating/obtaining one is *not* on-topic for SO), but you really may want to look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console instead

Comment: Thank you. I was think about doing a complete rewrite of the ASCII characters via script. But I didn't just realize that I could just change the font to a different font with the characters I need. Thank you for helping me.