# Why does C# returning "?"?

Tags: c#, types, integer, return, double

so I just started experimenting with C#. I have one line of code and the output is a "?".

Code: `Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow(Math.Exp(1200), 0.005d));`

Output: `?`

I am using Visual Studio and it also says `exited with code 0`.

It should output `403.4287934927351`. I also tried it out with Geogebra and it's correct as shown in the image so it's not infinity.
[image: image representing clamation]

Comment: Because it's trying to print out the infinity symbol, I'd imagine.

Comment: That's correct. You can configure your terminal to support Unicode characters, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console)

Comment: By the way, this prints `true`: `Console.WriteLine(double.IsInfinity(Math.Exp(1200)));`

Comment: Add the following to the start of your console app: `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;`

Comment: Probably you are confused as to why this returns infinity. That's because `Math.Exp(1200)` is too big number to be stored in a `double`, so already here it returns special "number" representing infinity, and from that point on all calculations just return infinity.

Comment: It's worth noting that .NET 5 changed the output for `double.Infinity` from `Infinity` to `∞`, as a side-effect of moving from NLS to ICU for localization (on Windows at least -- other platforms have always used ICU)

Comment: @canton7 but docs say that Infinity.ToString() returns `CultureInfo.NumberFormat.PositiveInfinitySymbol` (or negative infinity symbol) already.

Comment: @Evk Indeed, and `NumberFormat.PositiveInfinitySymbol` (which used to be sourced from NLS, and is now sourced from ICU) changed from `Infinity` to `∞` (for the main cultures, at least). The invariant culture still uses `Infinity`, though: that's hard-coded and isn't sourced from ICU

Comment: Ah, I guess my culture is not "main" then, since it alerady has this symbol as ∞

Comment: Which target framework is used? [.NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FLHZJ8) shows `Infinity` or `∞` symbol in output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# `double` type (which is returned by `Math.Exp` function) is a fixed-size type (64 bits), and so it cannot represent arbitrary large numbers. Largest number it can represent is `double.MaxValue` constant, and it's of order 10^308, which is less than what you are trying to compute (e^2000).

When result of computation exceeds maximum representable value - special "number" representing Infinity is returned. So

```
double x = Math.Exp(1200); // cannot represent this with double type
bool isInifinite = double.IsInfinity(x); // true
```

After you got this "infinity" - all other computations involving it will just return infinity back, there is nothing else they can do. So then whole expression `Math.Pow(Math.Exp(1200), 0.005d))` returns "infinity".

When you try to write result to console, it gets converted to string. The [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) for converting mentioned infinity to string are as follows:

> Regardless of the format string, if the value of a Single or Double
> floating-point type is positive infinity, negative infinity, or not a
> number (NaN), the formatted string is the value of the respective
> PositiveInfinitySymbol, NegativeInfinitySymbol, or NaNSymbol property
> that is specified by the currently applicable NumberFormatInfo object.

In your current culture, `PositiveInfinitySymbol` is likely "∞", but your console encoding likely cannot represent this symbol, so it outputs "?". You can change console encoding to UTF8 like this:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

And then it will show "∞" correctly.

There is no framework-provided type to work with arbitrary sized rational numbers, as far as I know. For integer there is `BigInteger` type though.

In this specific case you can do fine with just `double`, because you can do the same thing with:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Exp(1200 * 0.005d));
// outputs 403.4287934927351
```

Now there are no intermediate results exceeding capacity of `double`, and so it works fine.

For cases where it's not possible - there are third party libraries which allow to work with arbitrary large rationals.