# Outputing Unicode Values via different Output Encodings C#

Tags: c#, unicode, console-application, windows-console

I am experimenting with the Console Output Options and have noticed this:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Console.WriteLine("\u266F");
    Console.WriteLine("\u6F26");
```

So I set the Encoding to Unicode(UTF-16LE) and I am trying to output the sharp character
"\u266F"  This is the sharp in UTF-8
"\u6F26"  This is the sharp in UTF-16LE

You can see the output in the screenshot[image]

So I have 2 questions

1. Why does this "\u266F"  output a sharp when It is in UTF-8 and I have set the Encoder to Unicode
2. Why doesn't this output a sharp if it is in UTF-16LE and the Encoder is in UTF-16LE too.

Comment: A c# `System.String` is always encoded in UTF-16.  When you set [`Console.OutputEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?view=net-6.0) you are controlling how the console should **encode** the incoming strings for output.  It doesn't change how it interprets the encoding of the strings themselves; that is always UTF-16.  See: https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Strings and [Unicode Support for the Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-6.0#Unicode).

Comment: Thank you very much,  It is clear.
I would like to know why does the console output question marks when I do not write the line Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode; ?
Is there anything wrong with the DEFAULT encoding of the Console?

Comment: Keep in mind that the Windows Console is very very old.  Maybe 4 decades old?  So there is a lot of legacy stuff going on.  Before .NET, my (possibly incorrect) recollection is that the computer itself would have an active encoding, and all c/c++ strings would be interpreted according to that encoding. But things have evolved over the years, and now `Console.OutputEncoding` effectively specifies the subset of Unicode that the Console currently outputs, with anything not supported getting mapped to `?`.

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-6.0#Unicode): *In general, the console reads input and writes output by using the current console code page, which the system locale defines by default. A code page can handle only a subset of available Unicode characters, so if you try to display characters that are not mapped by a particular code page, the console won't be able to display all characters or represent them accurately.*

Comment: Here, you should be able to find the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5750227/4795779