# Cannot print special characters to console

Tags: c#

When I try to output "ᕦ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)ᕤ" to console it's just a bunch of question marks.

I have tried messing with System.Console.OutputEncoding with no success.

How can I achieve my utmost important goal of printing the "ᕦ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)ᕤ".

Comment: Most likely the font for the console does not support those characters.  I think you'l have to change the default font used for the console.

Comment: Probably has to do with UTF8-characters see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062875/show-utf8-characters-in-console

Comment: The console is ANSI by default. Making it unicode is a bit tricky, short answer being "don't". You probably don't want it to be *the* windows console, right? Just make a form that looks like the console :D

Comment: @Drifter: Nope; this has nothing to do with UTF-8 specifically. It has to do with the font the console uses and unicode in general: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works reasonably well (as in: the shape is more recognizable):

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
Console.WriteLine("ᕦ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)ᕤ");
Console.ReadLine();
```

**But** you need to change the console's default font to something like consolas. With font changed to Consolas it looks like:

[image: Screenshot / proof]

With the default font it looks like:

[image: Screenshot / proof]

And if you change the font but don't set the output encoding it looks like:

[image: Screenshot / proof]

The console's default encoding is `OEM Multilingual Latin 1; Western European (DOS)` e.g. "IBM850" or `OEM United States` e.g. "IBM437".

However, as suggested in other comments: don't. Just don't. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2062917/215042).