# How to write UTF-8 to Console in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, utf-8, console-application

I have a WPF application that also writes to `stdout` because it can operate in two modes, UI or console. The output contains non-ascii characters, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine("ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆ ®¯°±¹²³¼½¾¶·")
```

The result is a stream that I can redirect into a file and the file is encoded as `ISO-8859` but I want it to be `UTF-8`.
For console applications [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11812361/829755) suggests to set

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

But when I do that in my application I get

```
System.IO.IOException "The handle is invalid" when setting OutputEncoding
```

Comment: There is a mix of Latin and Greek characters. How those could be both concurrently encoded as `iso-8859-1` (Latin) and `iso-8859-7` (Greek) in a single `Console.WriteLine` command? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: you're right the greek letters are replaced with latin characters that look similar. I'll remove them because this is not the point. Anyway when I run the result through the linux `file` command I get "ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators", i.e. not "ISO-8859-1". What I want is UTF-8 and that does allow a mix of latin and greek letters, doesn't it?
Note that my source code is UTF-8, too.

Comment: That's why I have set _[Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support](https://superuser.com/a/1451686/376602)_, following [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: @JosefZ, that helped! thank you :-)
If you add it as answer I can accept it.

Comment: Please [post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others can find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by JosefZ:
There's a checkbox since Windows 10 insider build 17035 for setting the locale code page to UTF-8:

Control Panel > Cloc and Region > Region > Administrative > Change system locale... > Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support = true

[see here for more details](https://superuser.com/a/1451686/376602)

Answer (score 0):

This is the weirdest thing Microsoft made me do for Visual Studio 2019
and you have to REBOOT your PC :)

[image]