# when i try to catch an error and write something in cw in a catch block i get a question mark

Tags: c#, try-catch

simple program. why does it show "?" and not "you can't divide by zero" in a console window? only happens when i use doubles. everything is fine with integers.

```
using System;
using static System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSType;

namespace HelloWorld
{
  public class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      double x;
      double y;
      double divide;
      try 
      {
        x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        divide = x / y;
        Console.WriteLine(divide);
      }
      catch(DivideByZeroException ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("you can't divide by zero");
      }    
    }   
  }
}
```

this is what i get
[image]

Comment: double division does not throw DivideByZeroException because double can represent infinite values quite well: 1.0/0.0 => double.PositiveInfinity, 0.0/0.0 => double.NaN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistency in divide-by-zero behavior between different value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609698/inconsistency-in-divide-by-zero-behavior-between-different-value-types)

Comment: if you actually need to make it work you should just check if `y == 0` to print that message. The reason why you are seeing `?` it's because it was supposed to be infinite and that character `∞` isn't rendered

Comment: though this raises the question why didn’t you simply debug your code and check what actually happens instead of assuming it raised an exception

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

Comment: BTW you are getting a question mark instead of the infinity symbol because of an encoding which doesn’t support the character - here you can see how to switch to utf8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062875/show-utf-8-characters-in-console